# join python array after splitting from given index

Tags: python, django, string, join, split

I have a python string called `line` that I've split. `line` is a recurring string. I'm searching through an excel file and printing out each line that contains a specific word, i'll call it `search` which is a term that the user inputs. If the `line` doesn't contain `search` then it doesn't get printed.

I split the `line`, and printed out the `search_index` (index of the search term in the `line`).

```
s=line.split()
search_index = s.index(search) if inflected in s else "not in this line"
print(search_index)
```

If it doesn't exist in the line then the log will say "not in this line" instead of a number since it was crashing whe nI didn't include that.

What I awnt to do is join this split back together, but from a range with the searched term being teh middle. So, something like

```
new_line=[search_index - 5:search_index + 5]
```

but not sure if that's right since it gives me an error on the webpage of "syntax invalid"

How should this be properly done?

Comment: You have specified a range without an array or string. Perhaps you mean `new_line = line[search_index - 5:search_index + 5]`?

Comment: I tried that but it gives me an error:  unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: That would make sense for the lines where `search_index` has been assigned the string `"not in this line"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo (missing `line` before your range `[:]`) but there's another thing as well. If your `search_index` has been assigned a string, you can't subtract or add 5 to it.

I'm not sure of the context so you'll have to tweak this to your needs but this addresses those issues:

```
s=line.split()
if inflected in s:
    search_index = s.index(search)
    new_line = line[search_index-5:search_index+5]
else:
    print("not in this line")
```

Comment: I see, this fixed the issue! I placed the if statement inside a try except and that fixed my issues.

Comment: @user3325170 I'm glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you get the attribute of a list, you always have to put the name of the list before how you are calling it:

```
>>> line = 'hello world!'
>>> search_index = 3
>>> [search_index-3:search_index+3]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    [search_index-3:search_index+3]
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> line[search_index-3:search_index+3]
'hello '
>>>
```

Therefore, instead of `new_line = [search_index-5:search_index+5]`, use `new_line = line[search_index-5:search_index+5]`.

Here is another example:

```
>>> line = 'Hello this is django on python'
>>> line = line.split()
>>> search_index = line.index('django')
>>> new_line = [search_index - 2:search_index + 2]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    new_line = [search_index - 2:search_index + 2]
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> new_line = line[search_index - 2:search_index + 2]
>>> new_line
['this', 'is', 'django', 'on']
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to add the line in line[index...]!